# I am urbanAir for push notification,but i am not getting notification when I placed app on store for approval

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am us urbanair for push notification ,I tested application on developer profile it was working fine but when I used distribution profile ,now I am not getting any notification though chrone job is running on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new app (on Urban AirShip) that contains a new Application Secret key.

You must also remember to replace the secret keys in the code of the Release build.

You also must upload the Distribution Certificate you used to sign the Release (App Store version) build.

Answer (score 0):

Production (Ad Hoc & App Store) and development binaries require different APNs certificates. You may need to change your certificates.